# What is an engineering application for the R over Q vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I was able to find information on engineering applications for general vector spaces, but I can't find anything on this particular one or whether it is useful in engineering. Are there any applications of the real number over rational number vector space?

Comment: Have you taken a introduction to programming course? Do you know FEM simulations? Do you know that every number in a computer has floating point representation, and actually a rational? Hence, you never work with irrationals by doing computations of any kind?

Comment: The Dehn invariant lives in a quotient of the weird tensor product $\mathbb{R} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{R}$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehn_invariant#Definition ). Possibly a Hamel basis is needed in order to ensure that this quotient is not identically zero (whence Hilbert's third problem has a negative answer). But I don't know if this has any practical uses; how do we actually tell if two polyhedra are dissection-equivalent?

Comment: @darijgrinberg You should convert this into a serious answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably  no engineering applications of the vector space of reals $\mathbb R$ over the rationals $\mathbb Q$.  Almost certainly none. 
 There is no practical way of writing a basis for this particular vector space, so matrix computations would be extremely difficult to carry out.
And any basis is too large to store in any computer currently on the horizon.

As far as I know the only known use for this vector space is to provide counterexamples to unwary guesses, such as to show that discontinuous solutions of Cauchy's functional equation $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ exist.

Oh, but as I write, a possible application area occurs to me: engineering students are sometimes  associated with pranks, and maybe you could build a $\mathbb R/\mathbb Q$ prank somehow.